# Power Bi - Slicer to filter column names instead of column values

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, calculated-columns, measure

I am currently in the process of learning myself, Power Bi. However, I got myself stuck when I tried to create a slicer which can manipulate what to show or hide in a line graph, which is located bellow the slicer. In order to have a better understanding here is the table that I created:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Period</p>
</td>
<td>Module A&nbsp;</td>
<td>Module B&nbsp;</td>
<td>Module C&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CW01&nbsp;</td>
<td>80%</td>
<td>75%&nbsp;</td>
<td>90%&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CW02&nbsp;</td>
<td>82%&nbsp;</td>
<td>65%&nbsp;</td>
<td>92%&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CW03&nbsp;</td>
<td>83%&nbsp;</td>
<td>73%&nbsp;</td>
<td>88%&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My end goal is for the slicer to have the column names included in the line graph and hide/show the selected column names from the slicer into the line graph bellow it. However, whenever I include the column inside my slicer it results in putting the values of that columns instead just the column names. I managed to solve this issue by creating a new table, this time with the column names as values, but I was wondering if there would be a more elegant way to solve this problem. For example, would it be possible to create a measure, which takes the column names of a certain table or maybe a measure that will act as a column with manually defined values in it? I would be really grateful if you can help me get into this matter further. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your table raw data or you create a new table based on raw data? Because i found issue to use slicer to filter the line graph

Comment: You can't use a slicer on the column names, in this case unpivot you data, so the column name is in the row with the value